# Backing up Ubuntu to a Windows NAS

Tags: mount, backup, samba, rsync, nas

I have spent hours trying to replicate the function of Cobian Backup (Windows only) on Linux (Xubuntu): basically to schedule backups of certain folders to an external hard drive attached to a router (a Network Attached Storage / NAS).

I found lots of information on rsync and grsync (GUI for rsync), on Unison (seems very powerful), and chrontab, but I ran into several problems:

1. I would prefer to keep a mainly graphical setup with minimal command line interfaces ... this is not just for me (convenience) but for other users who are not fans of CLI.
2. I want to backup to a SMB shared folder (a Seagate Central) - grsync doesn't like it because it's not properly mounted.
3. I don't want to have to keep manually editing chrontab, etc.

I finally found what seems to be a workable solution, so I will be posting it below, but also providing a place for other *EASY* (or as easy as possible) solutions for 'minimally-techie' users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that seems to work and is (relatively) straightforward and (largely) GUI-based:

1. Install GRSYNC from the Ubuntu apps directory (or through apt-get install).
2. Install "Scheduled Tasks" / Gnome-Schedule using CLI / terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
   ```
3. Mount your NAS / external hard drive so that Linux recognizes it as if it was another hard drive. (NOTE: detailed instructions are available on the Ubuntu wiki named MountWindowsSharesPermanently - *if someone wants to make this a link, it would be great - I'm only allowed to post 2 links*). These steps assume you are accessing an unprotected / public folder. The wiki contains more information on different scenarios.

   1. Install cifs-utils: `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`
   2. Create a mount folder for the NAS folder you are mounting in the 'media' folder. You can do this either through your file manager (you may have to access it as super-user) or through CLI: `sudo mkdir /media/what-you-want-to-call-your-nas` (e.g. "/media/seagatecentral")
   3. Add your NAS to the /etc/fstab file. You can do this either by browsing to it in your file manager (again, with super-user status) or through CLI: `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.

      Add this line:

      ```
      //servername/sharename  /media/what-you-want-to-call-your-nas  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
      ```

      - Servername: the name of your NAS 'server' (easiest is to use the IP address, and assign it a static IP address in your router settings. If you can't do this you may be able to identify the non-IP address server name by browsing to it in your file manager).
      - sharename: the folder you want to mount (e.g. on Seagate Central, a default "Public" folder is created that could be used here, or another one like "MyName/Backups" so it would read "//ip-address-here/MyName/Backups")
   4. Remount your drives so the new 'drive' will show up: `sudo mount -a`
4. Create a backup using GRSYNC - most of the options are fairly straightforward, so setup the type of backup you want (NOTE: you are not scheduling it yet). A quick guide is available at [dedoimedo](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grsync.html).
5. Find the rsync command generated by GRSYNC: go to File --> Rsync Command Line (or just press Alt+R). Copy the entire command.
6. Create a scheduled task using Gnome-Schedule. This is fairly straightforward as well. In the "Command" field, paste the rsync command you copied from GRSYNC. For more information on Gnome-Schedule, you can check [everydaylinuxuser](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/10/an-everyday-linux-user-guide-to.html).

You should be all set now.